# Insitution I work in is corrupted. Does that affect my application?

Tags: visas

As I previously stated, I got hired 7 months ago, but the place I work with is known to be corrupted when it comes to get hired. Even I got hired through connections, like the rest of employees.  Do they have this info and does that affect my application?

Comment: Who is "they"? Your application for what? Why is this tagged visas? You need to include more information (location would probably help a lot.)

Comment: application for schengen or b2 visa? they are the officials in embassy?

Answer (score 1):

- The key thing about the job requirement for visa is **that you have a stable and well-paid job when you return**, because that makes more likely that you will return and less likely that you will overstay.
- Consular officials and the decisionmakers (who may not work in the consulate) have access to all sorts of info which is used to assess the credibility of the application. They don't reveal all their sources.
- I think you still haven't told us your nationality and destination. *That matters a lot.* A weekend trip from Russia to Finland differs from a month-long voyage from India to the UK.